# Cryengine 3.5 AI Tagpoint Not Working

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cryengine

I am unable to get my entity character "Human" (in Cryengine 3.5) to move towards a tagpoint.

Please find below a picture of my tagpoint flow graph:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsyaE.jpg

Unfortunately, despite generating AI and running the game multiple times including in areas where the Human cannot see the player (which breaks the flow graph), the AI just does not move towards the tagpoint.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug in Cry Engine and it is recommended users avoid this facility, downgrade there engine or request help from the developers directly.